# Choose list which is returned by def

Tags: python, user-defined-functions

I have a definition to separate some coordinates on specific properties.
For this separation I use 1 definition and within the definition i have 9 lists (different criteria's). Now for the output i just want the list defined by me. Otherwise I cannot use it for plotting.

```
def sorteerCord(cord):
    tweestijging=[]
    stijginggelijk=[]
    stijgingdaling=[]
    tweedaling=[]
    dalinggelijk=[]
    dalingstijging=[]
    tweegelijk=[]
    gelijkstijging=[]
    gelijkdaling=[]

    y=0
    while y<len(cord):
        lijst=cord[y]
        if (lijst[1]-lijst[0])>0.5:
            if (lijst[2]-lijst[1])>0.5:
                tweestijging.append(y)
            if (lijst[2]-lijst[1])<=0.5 and (lijst[2]-lijst[1])>=-0.5:
                stijginggelijk.append(y)
            if (lijst[2]-lijst[1])<-0.5:
                stijgingdaling.append(y)

        if (lijst[1]-lijst[0])<-0.5:
            if (lijst[2]-lijst[1])>0.5:
                dalingstijging.append(y)
            if (lijst[2]-lijst[1])<=0.5 and (lijst[2]-lijst[1])>=-0.5:
                dalinggelijk.append(y)
            if (lijst[2]-lijst[1])<-0.5:
                tweedaling.append(y)

        if (lijst[1]-lijst[0])<=0.5 and (lijst[1]-lijst[0])>=-0.5:
            if (lijst[2]-lijst[1])>0.5:
                gelijkstijging.append(y)
            if (lijst[2]-lijst[1])<=0.5 and (lijst[2]-lijst[1])>=-0.5:
                tweegelijk.append(y)
            if (lijst[2]-lijst[1])<-0.5:
                gelijkdaling.append(y)

        y=y+1       
    print raw_input()
    return raw_input()
```

Is their a way to define in my def what the output file is like (def sorteerdCord(cord,outpu=tweestijging)

Comment: what do you mean by "what the output file is like"? What is it like?

Comment: Based off of Google Translate, I found that this is Dutch. However, it would be useful to all if you changed the variable names to be more meaningful in English, because someone like myself who doesn't speak/understand Dutch, would have to look the names up.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that in the last two lines you want the user to input what output list to use but am not quite sure. You could use dictionary to map input strings to variables.

Something like:

```
def sorteerCord(cord, output):
    # all of your separation code
    outputmap = { 'tweestijging': tweestijging,
                  'gelijkstijging' : gelijkstijging,
                   # and more of those
                 }
    return outputmap[ output ]
```

And then call:

```
sorteerCord(cord, 'gelijkstijging')
```

You could of course also opt for returning all of the lists or keep them in a dictionary instead:

```
output = { 'tweestijging': [],
       'gelijkstijging': [],
        # etc
        }

 # code to manipulate lists goes here

return output
```

Then selecting one afterwards using the same technique.

Comment: I made the mistake of converting the whole list of list declarations into a dict literal, giving you plenty of time to answer before me! :-)

Comment: I wondered why I was first. The code race here at SO is vicious.

Comment: thank you glormph that was exactly what i meant. I'm sorry for my bad english explanation but indead this is what i need.